# Python to replace a symbol between between 2 words in a quote

Tags: python, text, delimiter, processor

trying to replace **comma** between 2 words **Durango and PC** in the second line by **&** and then remove the quotes " as well. Same for third line with **Orbis and PC** I would like to retain the rest of the lines using Python:

```
2,SIN-Rendering,Core Tech - Rendering,PC,147,Reopened
2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering,"Durango, PC",55,Reopened
3,SIN-Audio,AAA - Audio,"Orbis, PC",13,Open
...
... 
...
```

Like these, there can be 100 lines in my sample. So the expected output is:

```
2,SIN-Rendering,Core Tech - Rendering,PC,147,Reopened
2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering, Durango & PC,55,Reopened
3,SIN-Audio,AAA - Audio, Orbis & PC,13,Open
...
...
...
```

So far, I could think of reading line by line and then if the line contains quote replace it with no character but then replacement of symbol inside is something I am stuck with.

How to achieve this, any suggestion? Learning Python.

Comment: Could you please include more example of what you are targeting? Is it any group such as ("Word1, word2") to (Word1 & word2)?

Comment: why does "Orbis, PC" remain the same?

Comment: Are you targeting exactly ("Durango, PC") and no other groups such as ("Orbis, PC")?

Comment: Fixed the original question for other groups as well @AshishAcharya

Comment: Created an extension of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626343/remove-quotes-holding-2-words-and-remove-comma-between-them

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this. Write a regular expression that catches your string, and then use it to replace it.

It should look something like this:

```
\"(\w*),\ (\w*)\"
```

This will catch  your *Durango* and *PC*, and map both of them into two groups which you later use when you replace them.

Comment: Created an extension of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626343/remove-quotes-holding-2-words-and-remove-comma-between-them

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Add proper `if()` if you want to switch comma to ampersand only in second line:

This code goes trough all lines with  `..., "..., ...", ...` => `..., ... & ..., ...`

```
import re

expr = r'2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering,"Durango, PC",55,Reopened'

expr2 =  re.findall('"(.*?)"', expr)
if len(expr2)!=0:
    expr3 = re.split('"',expr)
    expr4 = expr3[0]+expr3[1].replace(","," &")+expr3[2]
    print(expr4)
```

Comment: created an extension of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626343/remove-quotes-holding-2-words-and-remove-comma-between-them

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
st = "2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering,\"Durango, PC\",55,Reopened"
res = re.sub(r'\"(.*),\ (.*)\"',lambda x : (" & ").join(re.findall(r'\"(.*),\ (.*)\"', st)[0]),st)
```

Comment: this closely works with what i expect but what if i have input like:

2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering,"Durango, Orbis, PC",55,Reopened ...how about 3 words inside for some lines and 2 words for others

Comment: the expected output should be 2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering, Durango & Orbis & PC,55,Reopened

Comment: created an extension of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626343/remove-quotes-holding-2-words-and-remove-comma-between-them