# Remove quotes holding 2 words and remove comma between them

Tags: python, process, delimiter, text-processing, data-processing

Following up on [Python to replace a symbol between between 2 words in a quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609461/python-to-replace-a-symbol-between-between-2-words-in-a-quote)

Extended input and expected output:

trying to replace **comma** between 2 words **Durango and PC** in the second line by **&** and then remove the quotes " as well. Same for third line with **Orbis and PC** and **4th line** has 2 word combos in quotes that I would like to process **"AAA - Character Tech, SOF - UPIs","Durango, Orbis, PC"**

I would like to retain the rest of the lines using Python.

**INPUT**

```
2,SIN-Rendering,Core Tech - Rendering,PC,147,Reopened
2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering,"Durango, PC",55,Reopened
3,SIN-Audio,AAA - Audio,"Orbis, PC",13,Open
LTY-168499,[PC][PS4][XB1] Missing textures from Fort Capture NPC face,3,CTU-CharacterTechBacklog,"AAA - Character Tech, SOF - UPIs","Durango, Orbis, PC",29,Waiting For
...
... 
...
```

Like these, there can be 100 lines in my sample. So the **expected output** is:

```
2,SIN-Rendering,Core Tech - Rendering,PC,147,Reopened
2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering, Durango & PC,55,Reopened
3,SIN-Audio,AAA - Audio, Orbis & PC,13,Open
LTY-168499,[PC][PS4][XB1] Missing textures from Fort Capture NPC face,3,CTU-CharacterTechBacklog,AAA - Character Tech & SOF - UPIs,Durango, Orbis & PC,29,Waiting For
...
...
...
```

So far, I could think of reading line by line and then if the line contains quote replace it with no character but then replacement of symbol inside is something I am stuck with.

Here is what I have right now:

```
for line in lines:
            expr2 =  re.findall('"(.*?)"', line)
            if len(expr2)!=0:
                expr3 = re.split('"',line)
                expr4 = expr3[0]+expr3[1].replace(","," &")+expr3[2]
                print >>k, expr4
            else:
                print >>k, line
```

but it does not consider the case in 4th line? There can be more than 3 combos as well. For eg.

```
3,SIN-Audio,"AAA - Audio, xxxx, yyyy","Orbis, PC","13, 22",Open
```

and wish to make this 
`3,SIN-Audio,AAA - Audio & xxxx & yyyy, Orbis & PC, 13 & 22,Open`

How to achieve this, any suggestion? Learning Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, by treating the input file as a `.csv` we can easily turn the lines into something easy to work with.

For example,

`2,Kenny Chong,Core Tech - Rendering, Durango & PC,55,Reopened`

is read as:

`['2', 'Kenny Chong', 'Core Tech - Rendering', 'Durango, PC', '55', 'Reopened']`

Then, by replacing all instances of `,` with `_&` (space) we would have the line:

`['2', 'Kenny Chong', 'Core Tech - Rendering', 'Durango & PC', '55', 'Reopened']`

And it replaces multiple instances of `,`s within a line, and when finally writing we no longer have the original double quotes.

Here is the code, given that `in.txt` is your input file and it will write to `out.txt`.

```
import csv

with open('in.txt') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)

    with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in reader:
            line = list(map(lambda s: s.replace(',', ' &'), line))
            outfile.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

The fourth line is outputted as:

`LTY-168499,[PC][PS4][XB1] Missing textures from Fort Capture NPC face,3,CTU-CharacterTechBacklog,AAA - Character Tech & SOF - UPIs,Durango & Orbis & PC,29,Waiting For`

Comment: Do note that you can use `csv.writer()` for writing csv files. Removes the need to do it yourself with `outfile.write(','.join(line) + '\n')`.

Comment: You are right, originally I just wanted full control over writing the lists. I think csv.writer would probably produce the same output anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this once: I could not find a single expression that could do this. So did it in a bit elaborate way. Will update if I can find a better way(Python 3)

```
import re
st = "3,SIN-Audio,\"AAA - Audio, xxxx, yyyy\",\"Orbis, PC\",\"13, 22\",Open"
found = re.findall(r'\"(.*)\"',st)[0].split("\",\"")
final = ""
for word in found:
    final = final + (" &").join(word.split(","))+","
result = re.sub(r'\"(.*)\"',final[:-1],st)
print(result)
```